# Terminal problem DWM

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-terminal, dwm

I got as my first desktop environment gnome. As i go to DWM and wanna call the terminal by `Alt+Shift+Enter`, the terminal opens in gnome environment, but not in dwm.

Comment: P.S Resolved problem by integrating other terminal in dwm (xterm). Still want to understand why gnomes one doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the source code of dwm there's a variable called "termcmd" assuming the terminal under gnome is called "gnome-terminal" you'll have to replace "st" with "gnome-terminal"